It looks like it let me vote without an account (it didn't actually)
Screenshot is below.
Steps to reproduce:

Go to a stack where you do not have an account.
Go to a post where you are able to vote.
Attempt to vote on the post.
Click the "X" on the "Join [whatever stack your on]" popup.
As shown in the screenshot below it will look kind of like you voted.

This works on every site (where I don't have an account) that I've tried it on, with both upvoting and downvoting, as well as on meta sites. The vote count does not actually change and nor does the users reputation.


Able to reproduce. It's a partial regression of this bug. The difference here is that it only applies if one isn't registered on the site, and can be worked around by clicking somewhere else after closing the dialog; the earlier bug occurred in all cases when one attempted to vote without having the ability.

This is the colour of the :focus style, not the :checked / [aria-pressed=true] style. Traditionally, focus is indicated by an outline, though :focus-visible has muddled things somewhat. I have re-tagged this as a design bug.
I'm a staunch advocate for leaving webpage styles up to the user agent, where possible. If Stack Exchange want to roll their own, they should consider reading:

How To Design Useful and Usable Focus Indicators by Aparna Pasi (October 2023)

Having played around a bit more, I think this colour was actually intended for the :active style.
